# Add a link to text using js and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a link to text using javascript and jquery. But when I tried it it will display [object Text] as the output. My attempt is as below.

```js
 var remId = $('#userId').text(); 
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var linkText = document.createTextNode(remId);
    a.appendChild(linkText);
    a.title = "my title text";
    a.href = "http://example.com";
    a.id="fre";
    document.body.appendChild(a);

    $('#userId').text(linkText);
    console.log(linkText);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
   <div class="two">
  <p id="userId">
   abc
  </p>
   </div>
    </div>
```

Here above linkText variable should display the value with text. So where could I get wrong?

Comment: Use `$('#userId').append(linkText);` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is too simple with only jquery**

```js
$('#userId').html('<a href="http://example.com" title="my title tex" id="fre"> '+ $('#userId').text() + ' </a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <p id="userId">
        abc
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I don't think it's XSS proof. That's the point why op is using `createTextNode `, right?

Answer (score 0):

You just have one issue with your approach. instead of using `text` property, use `html` property and pass your `a` element.

```js
$(function() { 
var remId = $('#userId').text(); 
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode(remId);
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "my title text";
a.href = "http://example.com";
a.id="fre";
document.body.appendChild(a);

$('#userId').html(a);

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <p id="userId">
        abc
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```